# Cómo generar una clave dependiendo de el producto que se elija y sus variantes

Tags: javascript, php, html

en una tienda de iluminación se tiene 3 categorías de productos y cada categoría tiene sus productos esos productos tienen variantes cómo los wats la forma el color y así cada variación tiene un código por ejemplo el color azul es Z

El tema es que hay que hacer un generador para que el cliente con ayuda de un formulario valla eligiendo primero la categoría luego el producto y luego las variaciones que existen y que al final se vallan concatenando las claves de lo que se elija para que se forma una clave para hacer el pedido sea fácil y rápido como recomiendan hacerlo busco consejos muchísimas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer es atreves de una serie de coincidencias ir sacando tu lista de productos que tengas las mismas características mostrárselas al cliente y que el decida que producto(s) quiere escoger, si es de esta manera lo puedes realizar atreves de una serie de consultas a tu backend trayendo el id guardándolo en una variable  e ir lo concatenando a la siguiente clave, claro si esto es lo que deseas hacer.

también podrías crear el script con algo de código y ponerlo aquí para poder ayudarte en donde tengas el problema y poder ayudarte

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).